# How can I hide the table row after its checkbox has been selected and the user hits submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table with a checkbox at the top to select all, and individual checkboxes on each row for the user to select. Currently the PHP works so that after each row has been selected and the delete(submit) button is pressed, it updates the DB accordingly. How ever the user can only see that this row has been deleted once they refresh the page. I would like to use some jQuery to hide whatever table row the user has selected, after they hit the submit button.

I've tried using variations of

```
$('#delete_message').closest('tr').hide();
```

But I can't seem to get that to work properly. The HTML is straight forward

```
<form name="bulk_action_form" action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post" onSubmit="return delete_confirm();"/>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""></th>
      <th class="col-md-3">From</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Subject</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Date</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody class="checkbox-group" data-toggle="toggle-checkbox">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="51"></td>
    <td>Person 1</td>
    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fullMessageModal51">Test Subject 1</a></td>
    <td>2015-11-09 15:34:25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="51"></td>
    <td>Person 2</td>
    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fullMessageModal51">Test Subject 2</a></td>
    <td>2015-11-09 15:34:25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="51"></td>
    <td>Person 3</td>
    <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fullMessageModal51">Test Subject 3</a></td>
    <td>2015-11-09 15:34:25</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="bulk_delete_submit" id="delete_message" value="Delete">
</form>
```

How can I make sure that it hides whatever table row is selected, and if all are selected how can I hide all of them.

You help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Edit: The PHP I am using to update the DB after the form submit

```
include_once('dbConfig.php');
 if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])){
  $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];
    foreach($idArr as $id){
    mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE message SET publish='n' WHERE id=".$id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deleting from ajax call ?

Comment: How do you call the delete function? If you do not use any ajax call, the only way to delete the items is sending the form to the server and thus, refresh the page

Comment: I've edited my question to include the PHP that updates the DB. It's not using ajax, I've tried using the answers below and they work for a brief moment and then the row reappears, I'm assuming this is because i'm not using ajax to send the delete function.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand correctly.

So you want to hide rows which are checked, on button click?
Here's how you can do it [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wov0h7ok/2/):

```
//this is how you can select all rows
$('#select_all').on('click', function(){
    if(this.checked == true)
    {
        $('.table tbody .checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }
    else{
        $('.table tbody .checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

$('#delete_message').on('click', function(){
    $('.table tbody').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').hide();
})
```

But if you want these rows to be hidden after refresh, you should create IDs for rows, then handle them in your PHP code. So, when you reload page, you would get those values, and hide rows with those IDs (or whatever you use).

Comment: Thank you, for some reason for me it hides the table row after I click the button, then it immediately comes back again, I've edited my question to include the PHP that is updating the DB in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery needs to find all the checked inputs inside the `.checkbox-group` and then find the closest `tr` to hide it.  Like here:

```
$("#delete_message").click(function(){
    $(".checkbox-group input:checked").closest("tr").hide();
});
```

For your select all/deselect all, you need to again look in the `.checkbox-group` and find **all** the checkbox controls and update them with the checked value of the `#select_all` checkbox.

```
$("#select_all").click(function(){
    $(".checkbox-group input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

To submit your form via ajax without refreshing the page (and having the rows pop back) you need to apply an `id` to your `form` of `bulk_action_form` and then utilize the following jQuery:

```
$("#bulk_action_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
          // Consider doing something here (like a saved message).
          console.log(response);
      }
   });
});
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9qmxfc0n/4/

If you still receive the rows coming back then you have an issue with your PHP script.

Comment: Your answer worked fine, however I get the same problem as mentioned above, the row disappears on button click, and then once the form is submitted it reappears.

Comment: @Rob88991 can you put your form actions/submits in your question?

Comment: @Rob88991, I have added ajax behaviors to help prevent your submission from resetting the rows.  Keep in mind that if it continues to occur then there is something on the PHP side that's not correct (also in your example, all your checkboxes have the same ``value`` of 51)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form then prevent then default and submit after.

```
 $('#delete_message').click(function(e)
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').hide();          
         $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
```

If your using Ajax however put this in your success function.